# Example of http2 connection coalescing in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, http2, koa

I've searched all over for any code example (using any API framework) with Node.js that shows the HTTP/2 connection coalescing feature (In HTTP/2 requests for assets across different hostnames can be made over a single connection).
For instance: an example that requests 2 assets from 2 different domains and gets them both on the same connection.

Can you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the [http/2 documentation for node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_http2session_and_sockets) do you not understand and want to ask a more specific question about?

Comment: You can read about connection coalescing for multiple hosts that resolve to the same IP address here: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/18/http2-connection-coalescing/.  This appears to me to be something that the http2 client does (typically the browser), not something that a nodejs server does.  The client has to try to figure out which separate hosts are actually the same server.